# MS CRM 2016 Performance Baseline

Tags: dynamics-crm, performance-testing

I'm a newbie about performance testing and I need to make a performance test on MS CRM 2016. But I need some baseline numbers to make comparison. There should be some acceptable numbers by the industry. For example; what should be the max CPU usage of a CRM server or database server etc. In fact, these number don't have to be directly related to CRM. It's a website anyway. I googled many things and times but I couldn't find any complete information. Does anyone have such information or guide me to find anything about it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your best starting point for Dynamics CRM is the [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 White Papers & Technical Documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2015/01/05/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2015-white-papers-technical-documentation/) and particularly a white paper named [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Performance and Scalability Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45905).